# adding up row values in VBAProject

Tags: vba, excel, nested-loops

Say I have EXCEL 1 column (100 rows) of integers with values between 1 and 10 (with lrow being the last row).  With VB, I am trying to add the rows UP TO a given sum (ex:25) to FIND THE ROW when the given sum (or less if adding the last row will bring the sum to over 25) is achieved.

```
For i = 1 To lRow
       Do While sum < 25
            sum= sum+ Cells(i, 1).Value
            Cells(2, 5).Value = sum
        Next j
        i = j-1
    Loop
Next i
```

var j doesn't increment.  It keeps adding the fist row.  WHY?

note: I want to continue to add the rest of the rows starting with the end position (row) of the first iteration.  The reason for why i=j-1 is there.

Comment: That code won't run because you have `Next j` with no corresponding `For`. Fix that first. Or post your real code.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need two loops:

```
For i = 1 to lRow
    Sum =Sum + ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
    If Sum >= 25 then exit for
Next i
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 5).Value = sum
Msgbox "Stopped at Row: " & i
```

to continue down the column and get a print out every time it exceeds 25:

```
For j = 1 To lrow
    For i = j To lrow
        Sum = Sum + ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
        If Sum >= 25 Then Exit For
    Next i
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value = Sum 
    Sum = 0   
    j = i
Next j
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go like follows

```
For i = 1 To lRow
    sum = sum + Cells(i, 1).Value
    If sum <= 25 Then i25 = i
Next
```

so:

- sum will store the total sum of the cells values
- i25 will store the row at which the sum was 25, or less if the sum exceeds 25 at row i25+1